# How to get date of last "pay period" end for a particular employee?

Tags: xml, kronos-workforce-central

I'm using a separate scheduling program to feed data to Kronos via API. I'm starting to use it to sign off timecards for employees (always for previous pay period), but I need to get the date to which the timecard is signed off as we have different pay cycles. So, after sending the below request, how do I determine the date through which Kronos signed off the timecard?

```
<Request Action="SignOff">
    <ApproveSignoff>
        <Employee>
            <PersonIdentity PersonNumber="XXXXXX"/>
        </Employee>
    </ApproveSignoff>
</Request>
```

If it's possible to get the last signed off date of the employee's timecard, that'd be even better.

Comment: I happened to stumble into this question and don't know anything about kronos. But if it supports selection by using xpath, this question can probably be answered. So, if xpath is supported, please edit your question with the xml form of the response to the request.

Comment: It does not support xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution for this. In case any others are following in my footsteps, here's what I've found.

Make a Load call on the Timesheet:

```
<Request Action="Load">
    <Timesheet>
        <Employee>
            <PersonIdentity PersonNumber="12345"/>
        </Employee>
        <Period>
            <TimeFramePeriod PeriodDateSpan = "01/01/2050 - 01/01/2050" TimeFrameName = "9" />
        </Period>
    </Timesheet>
</Request>
```

I used 1 Jan 2050 to avoid getting irrelevant timesheet info if possible. Within the response, you'll get a  tag. Within that tag, if the employee had ever been signed off, will be a "ManagerSignoffDateTime" property with the date to which that employee's timecard is signed off. If they've never been signed off, that property will be absent. Hope that helps someone.